# Projects are invisible in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse projects and its content are invisible and cursor asking for alt+click to show the project.Any Idea.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do you use working sets?

If so check to make sure that the one in the eclipse explorer (navigator or whatever) is referring to the same working set, or is set to view all working sets.

If not, do you need to import the eclipse project?